# Apache rewrite read destination from map files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to dynamically rewrite urls in Apache by reading the mapped destination url from an alias file (one for each url). Here is my directory structure:

```
/websites
  /.aliases
    alias-of-site-1 (file containing 0ad5c94df074c13f)
    alias-of-site-2 (file containing 50d9a12e9619d041)
    (...)
  /0ad5c94df074c13f (website subdirectory for alias-of-site-1)
  /50d9a12e9619d041 (website subdirectory for alias-of-site-2)
  (...)
```

When a visitor navigate to http://example.com/alias-of-site-1, I need to read the real subdirectory of the website from the file `/websites/.aliases/alias-of-site-1`, then rewrite the url as http://example.com/0ad5c94df074c13f

I find the Apache `RewriteMap` directive, but it only seems to work when all key / values are in one file. In my case, each alias has its own file.

Comment: You can have `RewriteMap` [use a program](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg), so that program can read from as many files as you like and return the answer. But it's probably better for performance to combine the files with some offline process and read from that combined map.